# iOS: UILabel & UIButton in a table cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uibutton, uilabel, cell

I am trying to display a Label and a button side-by-side in a UITableViewCell. The button sits at the right end & the Label sits at the left end. The label can host a long text and should get truncated if the text would flow out of bounds (I do not want to reduce the font size, etc.). Needless to say, I want this to work for both the orientations.

If I use UITableViewCellStyleDefault (without adding a button) & set a long text for the default label, I observe that the label auto-resizes perfectly when the orientation changes. Most probably because its autoresizingMask is set to `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin.`  Now, the way I see it, I could insert my button, and make the label truncate properly, if I could configure the value of the right margin that is being used by default (to accommodate the button). I essentially want it to auto-resize within the bounds that I specify. Is there a way this can be accomplished?

I would not prefer listening to each orientation change and setting the bounds of the label's frame. Any other feasible solution?

Comment: Have you considered creating a UITableViewCell subclass?  That would give you total control over subview auto-resizing.

Comment: Thanks Mark! Yes, I have considered sub-classing and overriding `layoutSubviews`, but I would prefer that to be the last resort. It seems like an overkill for something like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally went with subclassing `UITableViewCell` & overriding `layoutSubViews`. Thanks Mark!